# Why are (many) bike multitools not stainless, unlike penknives?

Tags: multi-tool

This has been bugging me for a while.  I've always had penknives/pocket knives (Swiss Army knives), and even the cheap ones are made of stainless steel.  They include screwdrivers and other similar tools to bike multitools.  But my bike multitools tend to rust, badly, if they get wet (and they do get wet, as I ride in all weathers in a wet country).  The only stainless ones I've got are small and effectively incomplete, though I see that Lezyne make one and possibly Topeak (or maybe that's just the body)

So is there a good (engineering) reason why bike multitools are rarely stainless?

Comment: I guess you can think the other way around: would you want to eat something you've cut with an extremely rusty knife ? Then knives *have to* be stainless.

Comment: @VincentFourmond many kitchen knives are carbon steel - but cared for properly that's not a problem.

Comment: E.g. the Crankbrothers M19 and probably others come with an aluminum&plastic case that is somewhat watertight. Unless submerged, it should keep the tool dry. You could add a plastic bag inside to improve water resistance...

Comment: @Erlkoenig I'm no weight weenie, but a case for a single tool is dead weight and bulk.  I uses a reasonably well-sealed tool bottle under the downtube, but that has been known to get immersed, and I seem to have to open my tool case in the rain quite often.  Once some rain gets in, it stays there

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the reason is hardness for the [tool steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tool_steel). With carbon steel you can achieve harder steel, at the cost of some brittleness, at much lower cost. There are some very hard stainless powder steels but they are also very expensive.

Some CrV steels used for tools have some rust protection due to the chromium content, but are not fully stainless. Also, even stainless steels can and do rust. Especially the harder types.

Note that cheap stainless knives are usually pretty soft and require frequent honing.

Comment: Victorinox isn't cheap though and those tools are tough - I wish they made a bike tool though I probably couldn't afford it.  They probably use the good stainless you mention.

Comment: Victorinox, as far as I know, does not really use particularly hard steel (HRC 53), rather very corrosion resistant ones,  and is among the cheaper mass-produced brands. Compare with, also mass-produced, Spyderco.

Comment: Note that European even professional chef knives (e.g. Zwilling, Wuesthoff) tend to be softer and more corrosion resistant and they are expected to be honed regularly.

Comment: I've had really cheap knives ; Victorinox hold an edge noticeably better than those both  in the kitchen and in the wilds - but they're certainly more like decent everyday kit than high-end

Comment: I suppose given how little engagement you get in some bike hex head fasteners, which also use undersize tools compared to other applications, you really don't want the tool rounding off so need greater hardness

Comment: Tools are quite often used with greasy hands and tend to be slightly oily, so that they won't rust too easily. It's different for knives with water, aggressive plant juices etc.

Comment: This is largely correct, but in turn begs the question of why many bike multitools don’t have a good passivation layer on their metal parts. Ferritic nitrocarburization is obviously way too expensive for this type of thing, but parkerization is relatively cheap and would measurably improve the useful life of many such tools in particularly wet environments.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn mine seem mainly to be plated (don't know if chrome or nickel, but silvery) and the plating is easily damaged

Comment: I have only one plated and that one is very simplistic (only a few hex keys). Also, the corners are not too sharp. I bet even parkerizing is not worth it for most aplication, my tools are not rusty anyway, the inside of my saddlebags does not get too wet too often. Expedition riders might look for some special multitools for wet environments.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: Also those tools are mostly bought with the after-thought not having to use them. I think that in the past ten years my most frequently used tools were the tyre levers. Would be interesting to find a larger scale survey on the use of saddlebag hardware.

Comment: Actually, some stainless steel tools I encountered were both softer **and** more brittle than a decent tool steel ones.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, with stainless, it's either soft, or brittle, or both, or [ten times more expensive](https://www.kctool.com/wera-022720-metric-stainless-steel-ball-end-hex-key-set/).

There are stainless bike [multitools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001GSMNSM) in the usual (unergonomic) format but... meh, one of the comments says "the bit snapped". If you can't trust the tool to fix the bike, then, well... And the bits are not replaceable, so when they snap, ka-chink, buy a new tool.

I've got this tool:

[image]

I put it in a plastic bag, yet after a few years the bits got rusty. But on this tool, they are easily replaceable, which might actually solve your problem.

Even if the ratchet rusts and seizes, it'll still be usable (just without the ratchet action).

The chain rivet tool is the best I've used. The tool is very ergonomic and a pleasure to use. In fact I used it more for DIY and screws/bolts in tight places, than on the bike.

If you really like rain, and don't like rusty tools, you could use just a a set of bits and a small "waterproof" chrome plated hex wrench that fits the bits:

[image]

There are also swivel head versions available.

Comment: That tool does look reasonable, but by the time I'd added the other things I've got on mine I may as well carry a non-bike mini socket set, chain tool, a mini leatherman (I may end up doing something like that when I replace the rusty one)